# Add UILabel to UITableView - iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am an iOS development newbie. I have a settings screen which is a UITableView. I want to add some explanation to it. I am using the following code to do it, but it skews up the text completely. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
UILabel *subjectLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 175)];
subjectLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
subjectLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
subjectLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(10.0)];
subjectLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//bodyLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;   
subjectLabel.text = @"mytext";

settingTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,  320, 370) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease]; 
settingTableView.dataSource = self;
settingTableView.delegate = self;
[settingTableView addSubview:subjectLabel];
[self.view addSubview:settingTableView];
```

Comment: Do you want to add a UILabel to a TableView, or a TableViewCell?

Comment: I want to add a header to the entire table

Comment: Use UITableViewController as data source and UITableViewDelegate protocol to add a header to your table. Class reference: http://goo.gl/SXpS5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `tableViewHeader` is a `UIView` which is set as the `tableViewHeader` property of a tableView. If you want to have a `UILabel` in a header view, make a separate `UIView` (either in code, or in a nib), and set it as the `tableView.tableHeaderView` property. More information can be found here: [TableView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

create a view in your view controller and add your lable to that and bind it ...

IBOutlet UIView *headerView1;

and add this code

```
settingTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion1 : You could have create a separate view which contains your UILabel and place above the UITableView and place your tableView y position would be from the height of the UIView.

Remark : This is useful because when you scroll the tableView the default header will be stick to top.

Suggestion2 : you can use viewForHeaderInSection delegate method. where you can create a view and add the UILabel. viewForHeaderInSection returns the UIView, which you can return your view which contains the UILabel

Remark : when you scroll the tableView the default header will move along with your tableView